# Twitter follow button appears as link in Angular templates

Tags: twitter, angularjs, twitter-follow

One page app, where there are user-profile pages(that you change dynamically).

This doesnt work, it appears as link

```
<a href='https://twitter.com/{{user.twitter}}' class='twitter-follow-button' data-show-count='false' data-size='large'>Follow @{{user.twitter}}</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

[image]

If it reinitializes the code it doesn't work either

```
<div ng-show="user.twitter" ng-bind-html-unsafe="user.twitter|followButton">
```

Comment: I have a similar problem but I'm totally confused by your question and answer :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I forgot about Iframe, there's no option on twitter when you generate the button. So it works!

```
<iframe ng-show="user.twitter" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
              src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets/follow_button.html?screen_name={{user.twitter}}"
              style="width:300px; height:20px;"></iframe>
```

Also very important: iframes update history. To solve this problem I generate element iframe dynamically and then appendChild it to the location where it is supposed to be.

Here's a good example: http://nirlevy.blogspot.com/2007/09/avoding-browser-history-when-changing.html

Answer (score 5):

I'm currently working on an Angular app where I need to implement such widgets - from Facebook, Twitter, Google+ and Pinterest.

Although I wasn't able to make the Facebook button work without using its `iframe` form, the other three work like charms (read on).

The real issue with Angular seems to be the asynchronous Javascript codes these platforms usually provide (which dynamically create a script tag calling the actual JS code needed to make the button work). If you call the right JS file directly (and synchronously), it works great.

Example for Twitter :

```
<!-- This won't work : -->

<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url={{ $myEscapedUrl }}" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>



<!-- This will (note I'm using the same URL for the script) : -->

<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url={{ $myEscapedUrl }}" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
<script src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
```

Comment: Worked at first for the Follow button, but then I suddenly had two identic buttons next to each other... Now tried @mïchael-makaröv's solution and it works so far..